# numbers which are equal to their index value

Tags: python, sorting, indexing

how do i Find the numbers which are equal to their index value and print them in sorted order. Given a number n followed by n numbers

for example:
INPUT
6 7 3 3 4 5
OUTPUT
3 4 5

Comment: What sorts of things have you tried thus far?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This also looks like homework. If that is correct, please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Perfect use case for `enumerate`

```
print ([n for i, n in enumerate([6,7,3,3,4,5]) if i == n])
```

`i` is your index
`n` is your list entry

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a listcomp:

```
   output = [x for x in range(len(input)) if input[x]==x]
```

Comment: I'm curious what could lead to `output` not already being sorted?

Comment: Actually yeah you are right, doing it with range will automatically sort it. I'll edit now!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is in js but the logic same

let arr =  "INPUT 67 3 3 4 5 OUTPUT 3 4 5"

```
let joined = arr.split("")
let box = []
let arrayIndex = joined.forEach((item,idx)=>{
  if(idx == item){
    box.push(item)
  }
})

console.log(box.sort())
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In case you want to return a list as output

```
arr = []
size_of_array = int(input("Enter the size of array : "))
for i in range(size_of_array):
    element = int(input("Enter the number : "))
    arr.append(element)

array = []
for i in range(size_of_array):
    if arr[i] == i+1:
        array.append(i+1)
print(f'Value equal to index : {array}')
```